# New line delimited input stream written to file

Tags: go

I am new to GoLang and I might be trying to do something that isn't possible. Any help would be appreciated.

My question is how can I create a server that will get a message that will be delimited by a new line character and once the new line character is received I want to write the contents of the buffer to a unique file?

The server logic I have seems pretty standard. Below is my handleConnection function where I am attempting to perform the task I described above:

```
func handleConnection(conn net.Conn) {
  // closes the connection on exit
  defer func() {
    if err := conn.Close(); err != nil {
      log.Println("error closing connection: ", err)
    }
  }()

  // create a buffer for the incoming data
  buf := make([]byte, 4096)

  // read the incoming connection into the buffer
  size, err := conn.Read(buf)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("error reading: ", err.Error)
  }

  s := string(buf[:size])
  fmt.Println(s)
  // set the files permissions
  perm := os.FileMode(0777)
  // writes to the file and generates an err value
  err := ioutil.WriteFile("adt_output.txt", buf[:size], perm)
  // if err is not nol show the error
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }

}
```

Comment: What is your question/issue?

Comment: updated for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example use the following pattern to read until your termination byte:

```
    r := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    for {
        yourLine, err := r.ReadBytes(10)
        ... write your file ...
    }
```

Similar there is also `r.ReadString('\n')` which would too.